# Apply SSL certificate in a bigger context

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

In my **default-ssl**

```
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName example.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example2.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias subdomain1.*
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/subdomain1
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias subdomain2.*
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/subdomain2
 </VirtualHost>
```

I would like to apply the SSL certificate to the domain but apply a document root to different subdomains.

For some reason,

```
https://subdomain1.example.co/test is SECURE
https://subdomain1.example2.co/test is NOT SECURE
```

I have a wildcard SSL certificate for both.

Both should work.

Why can I designate SSL to all example.co and it's subdomains without a problem? Yet I can't do the same with example2.co?

I am trying to avoid creating lots of code for things are are pretty logical. Is there a shorter way to do this (**my only solution**):

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example2.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain1.example.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/subdomain1
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain1.example2.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2/subdomain1
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain2.example.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/subdomain2
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain2.example2.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2/subdomain2
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working with VirtualDocumentRoot:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example2.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias *.example.co
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/%-3
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias *.example2.co
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2/%-3
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
```

In this config for every subdomain the document root is set dynamically. The `%-3` takes the third part (counted from the right) of the requested domain and adds it to the path. For example `sub1.example.co` will result in `/var/www/html/example/sub1` and `abcd.example2.co` will result in `/var/www/html/example/abcd`. If you add a subdomain e.g. `sub123.example.co` you don't even need to touch this config because the path for this subdomain is set dynamically :)

Additional Info: There are subtle differences between `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`:

> `ServerName` can accept port numbers as well, while ServerAlias cannot.
>
> `ServerAlias` can accept wildcards (eg. *.mywebsite.com), while ServerName cannot.

That's why you should use ServerAlias instead of ServerName for wildcard subdomains. I don't know if ServerAlias is working without ServerName. If not just add a ServerName line with a random subdomain name eg. `any.example.co` to the two wildcard subdomain vhosts ;)

---

Link to post where I got initial info about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566226/creating-wildcard-sub-domain-using-apache-virtualhost

Link to apache2 docs about this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html